# KnockOut JS, DOM not reflect to observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

Refer to [this code (Origin Version)](http://jsfiddle.net/SimonYong/j8K29/2/).

I can't get my value update when I key in something to my added choice text box.

It work after I push an object into the observableArray. [See here (Modified Version).](http://jsfiddle.net/SimonYong/j8K29/3/)

But I think there should be a solution for me to directly use observableArray like Origin Version instead of push an object to the array like Modified Version.

Help appreciated.

Comment: It's interesting that it adds text boxes if you initialise the array with items in it. There seems to be missing the two-way databind

Comment: First, your original version pushes an empty string into the array (not an observable), so there would be no reason to expect the binding to work. 

With that said, this won't work even if you push an observable (e.g. `self.Choice.push(ko.observable(""))`) because the current KO code unwraps the individual elements of the array for the foreach binding. I don't think there is a currently a way around it other than having actual objects (with observable properties) in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hackish way to get around the [foreach](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/482) problem: http://jsfiddle.net/j8K29/7/

`ko.observable(ko.observable(""))` has the outer observable unwrapped by `foreach` and the inner observable remains.

I also changed your `removeChoice` function to reflect this change.